# ViewController sensors still firing after pop in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a part of my project where a user signs out.  I'm doing a typical popTo where I pop back to the first viewcontroller.  The problem is that I have sensors is still running and triggering print statements from the viewcontrollers that should have been popped off the stack and no longer exist.  Below I have my pop to root code.  The parts that are commented out are different pop methods I've used that all end the same result, I end up at the proper viewcontroller but it seems the one with the sensor is still running.  Any help would be great thanks.  I'm not including any code from the viewcontroller with the sensors because it shouldn't exist so the code in it should be irrelevant (might not but I doubt it).

```
if let nav = self.navigationController {
     let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
     nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
} else {
     self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

Comment: Show the sensor-related code, and remove the commented-out code.

Comment: Can I ask what in particular you are looking for?  I only ask because there is a lot of sensor code and I mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you hold strong reference to your ViewControllers so they don't get released. This means they will continue working even if they are not in the stack.

Probably check for retain cycles in your code. Do sensors keep strong reference to your ViewControllers while your VCs hold strong reference to your sensors? Just a guess.

Put a print in your ViewControllers deinit() method so you will see if they get destroyed or not.

Comment: Yea I'm almost positive its a retain cycle with a collectionview.  I think the sensors might just be a bi-product of the the controller not being destroyed.